# Display function of EBImage package do not show interactive image in shinyapps.io

Tags: image-processing, shiny, shinyapps

I'm programming a shiny app for image analysis using R and EBImage package. The shiny app run locally successfully. After some trials, I want to access to app via shinyapps.io platform.

In shinyapps.io, the app renders images (static) display correctly, but not the interactive one. It remains blank.

¿Some idea?

Thanks

This is the code:

```
library("shiny")
library("EBImage")

ui <- fluidPage(

# Application title
titlePanel("Image display"),

# Sidebar with a select input for the image
sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
     fileInput("image", "Select image")
),

# Show a plot of the generated distribution
mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Static raster", plotOutput("raster")),
    tabPanel("Interactive browser", displayOutput("widget"))
  )
)
)

)

server <- function(input, output) {

img <- reactive({
f <- input$image
if (is.null(f))
  return(NULL)        
readImage(f$datapath)
})

output$widget <- renderDisplay({
req(img())
display(img())
})

output$raster <- renderPlot({
req(img())
plot(img(), all=FALSE)
})

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This is a known issue, which I've reported in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/shinyapps-users/ebimage|sort:date/shinyapps-users/koR1K93aSCA/_DF51zqJBwAJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon this problem as well. I think that caused by fact that the display function is designed to be used from interactive sessions.

The fix consists simply in adding the method parameter to the display call. So your code should be:

```
...

output$widget <- renderDisplay({
  req(img())
  display(img(), method = 'browser') # <- this should make the trick
})

...
```